# Line Renderer Position Issue - Unity 5.3.5

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am following a unity tutorial on shooting lasers. In the tutorial, a Line Renderer is applied to the gun tip in order to shoot from it. As soon as the Line Renderer is applied, it points it in a straight line as shown below:

[image]

Now when I try to apply the Line Renderer, it is placed next to the gun as shown below:

[image]

How can I adjust this to be in straight line? I have tried checking the rotation and positioning of the Gun tip which is an empty gameobject but no luck. Please help!

**EDIT:**

Adding the hierarchy:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Uhm...this really isn't enough information for us to help. Where is the code you are using to manipulate the line renderer? Are you supplying it any points to draw a line between?

Comment: I have not put any code yet, just applied the line renderer to the empty gameobject which is present at the tip of the gun. I am adding the screenshot of hierarchy. The gun tip is nested down in the First Person Controller.

Comment: If you review the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-LineRenderer.html), it should become clear that a Line Renderer needs to be supplied with an array of two or more points before it can properly draw a line. Try adding a bit of code to do that, or even just manually setting those points in the editor properties of the Line Renderer.

Comment: @Serlite Okay I will try that and get back. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all when ever you add linerenderer component to an object by default its vertex count is 1 also it has some width , you can see that pink small line in your attached image.
 So all you have to do is set some of its properties like

```
 LineRenderer.SetVertexCount()
 LineRenderer.SetWidth()
```

Now set your vertex count to 2
 Then you can access these two vertex by its index (0 and 1)
 set first vertex to your starting point(Gun point) and second point to your end point(destination).

```
//Line renderer component is attached to gun
     LineRenderer linerenderer = GetComponent<LineRenderer >();
     lineRenderer.SetVertexCount(2);
     lineRenderer.SetPosition(0, "GUN TIP POSITION HERE");
     lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, "DESTINATION POSITION HERE");
```

And when your job is done dont forget to set its vertex count back to zero:)

```
lineRenderer.SetVertexCount(0);
```